# Convert to decimal and do OrderBy

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

My data table contains all string columns but in some columns we are filling numeric values. when I do orderby on datatable of that numeric column, it is not ordering properly. before order my table looks

```
Name    Account Department
Kiran   1100    CSC
Subbu   900     CSC
Ram     500     CSC
Raj     800     CSC
Joy     400     CSC
```

after order it looks like

```
Name    Account Department
Kiran   1100    CSC
Joy     400     CSC
Ram     500     CSC
Raj     800     CSC
Subbu   900     CSC
```

My code:

```
public DataTable sortData(string columnName)
{
   DataTable dt1=new DataTable();
   return  dt1=dataMgr[DatabaseFileNames.ControlDatabase]["OrderedTableName"]
              .Select("Department='CSC'")
              .OrderBy(x=>!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Field<string>(columnName)))
              .CopyToDataTable();
}
```

Comment: In your example, what are you passing for `columnName`? Also, is `Account` column a numeric column or not?

Comment: my table may contain empty values also.

Comment: @MarcoForberg that says the "datatable" - Im asking about the source of the data - the database.

Comment: @Jamiec okay good point

Comment: can you add leading zeros to your strings?

Comment: im passing Account column, and all my columns are of data type string.

Comment: Why in the world are you storing clearly numeric data in a non-numeric field in the database? I kind of understand why in the datatable you might want all strings (its still bizarre)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought about this quite some time and the solution i came up with is shockingly obvious: Essentially ordering is all about comparing - so why don't we just write a custom `Comparer`...

```
public class MyComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    private readonly string _columnName;
    public MyComparer(string columnName)
    {
        _columnName = columnName;
    }

    public int Compare(string leftValue, string rightValue)
    {
        double leftDouble, rightDouble;

        switch (_columnName)
        {
            case "Account":
                if (Double.TryParse(leftValue, out leftDouble) && Double.TryParse(rightValue, out rightDouble))
                {
                    return leftDouble.CompareTo(rightDouble);
                }
                else
                {
                    return String.Compare(leftValue, rightValue);   
                }
            default:
                return String.Compare(leftValue, rightValue);
        }
    }
}
```

...and then simply add it to the OrderBy...

```
public DataTable sortData(string columnName)
{
   DataTable dt1=new DataTable();
   return  dt1=dataMgr[DatabaseFileNames.ControlDatabase]["OrderedTableName"]
              .Select("Department='CSC'")
              .OrderBy(x => x.Field<string>(columnName) ?? String.Empty,
                            new MyComparer(columnName)
                      )
              .CopyToDataTable();
}
```

... and we're done and can even extend that solution to use other data types e.g. `DateTime`.

Answer (score 3):

Your `OrderBy` should look somewhat like this:

```
.OrderBy(x => double.Parse(x.Field<string>(columName)))
```

Of course that assumes that all your values are actually parsable as `double`.

If you need to have it work for non-numerical columns also, I don't think you'll get around having to differentiate based upon the column name. (I. e. you'd have to have some mapping between *columnName* and an `IComparer`.)

That might look somewhat like this:

```
IComparer comparer = null;
// instead of a switch/case you could also have a Dictionary<string, IComparer> for example...
switch(columName)
{
    case "Account": comparer = Comparer<double>.Default;
                    break;
    default: comparer = Comparer<string>.Default;
                    break;
}

// so your OrderBy would look like this:
.OrderBy(x => x, comparer)
```

The cleaner solution would definitely be having the correct data types for the columns in the table.

Comment: Careful. The order by column's name is passed to this method as parameter so it might as well be the name column

Comment: user can pass "Name" column also..code should work for all columns

Answer (score 2):

You can simply pad `string` containing `int` value with leading `0` for sorting to work properly:

```
.OrderBy(x => x.Field<string>(columnName)?.PadLeft(10, '0') ?? "0")
```

You will have to define size to be big enough (10?) and some value for `null` to sort it as you prefer (in case of using `"0"` they will appears first).

Comment: That's clever, didn't think of that. Though you'll have problems in non-numerical columns.

Comment: Clever idea, but I'm afraid this will cause problems if the data is to be sorted by Name

Comment: @MarcoForberg, for negative values or floating numbers this won't work as well. But idea should be clear and it's up to OP to decide whenever to use it or not.